# Discover who created a CloudTrail and how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudtrail

I am doing a bit of discovery on my current AWS environment and was trying to understand how the existing CloudTrail was created and who is the owner?

By "How" I mean - was it created using some CloudFormation template or via the Console or via any other means.

I could not find any CloudTrail resource created in any of the CloudFormation stacks I could see in the account.

Could somebody suggest if there is a way to find it out?

Comment: CloudTrail can probably tell you who created a CloudTrail! However, if it wasn't activated at that time, there would be no record to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to determine how the CloudTrail resource was created. The only thing you can do is to check whether any CloudFormation stack is referencing the trail as you already did.

The owner of a trail resource is always an AWS account.
More specific, it is either (a) the account owner if it is a non-organization trail or (b) the organization's master account if it is an organization trail. [1]
You can determine the owner account from the trail ARN: `arn:aws:cloudtrail:region:account-id:trail/trailname`. [2]

e.g. `arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:123456789012:trail/mytrailname` belongs to the account with ID *123456789012*.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/how-cloudtrail-works.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-cloudtrail